# How to generate Java source from WSDL in Pom.xml?

Tags: java, wsdl, pom.xml

I have a pom file which is generating source from WSDL files which is designed something like this.

```xml
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <id>Id1</id>
        <goals>
               <goal>wsimport</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <wsdlLocation>wsdl/HelloService.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
         <wsdlFiles>
                <wsdlFile>HelloService.wsdl</wsdlFile>
        </wsdlFiles>
        <staleFile>
                ${project.build.directory}/jaxws/stale/HelloService.wsdl.stale
        </staleFile>
        </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
        <id>Id2</id>
        <goals>
               <goal>wsimport</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <wsdlLocation>wsdl/GoodByeService.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
         <wsdlFiles>
                <wsdlFile>GoodByeService.wsdl</wsdlFile>
        </wsdlFiles>
        <staleFile>
                ${project.build.directory}/jaxws/stale/GoodByeService.wsdl.stale
        </staleFile>
        </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
       <target>2.1</target>
       <xjcArgs>
        <xjcArg>-XautoNameResolution</xjcArg>
       </xjcArgs>
       <bindingDirectory>src/jaxws</bindingDirectory>
       <keep>true</keep>
       <wsdlDirectory>src/jaxws/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
       <packageName>com.test.hello.soap</packageName>
    </configuration>
```

This is working really fine. And both the wsdl files are generated in the packageName (`com.test.hello.soap`) but I want the wsdl file with Id2 to be generated in a separate packageName or location.

Can someone tell me how to do that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<configuration>` tag at the bottom of your example defines config values that are common between the two executions.

If you want the value of `<packageName>` to have one value for Id1 and another value for Id2, you simply need to move the `<packageName>` config value into the `<configuration>` block for each execution.

So, it looks like :

```xml
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>Id1</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>wsimport</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <wsdlLocation>wsdl/HelloService.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
            <wsdlFiles>
                <wsdlFile>HelloService.wsdl</wsdlFile>
            </wsdlFiles>
            <staleFile>
                ${project.build.directory}/jaxws/stale/HelloService.wsdl.stale
            </staleFile>
            <!-- packageName value for Id1 -->
            <packageName>com.test.hello.soap</packageName>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>Id2</id>
        <goals>
           <goal>wsimport</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <wsdlLocation>wsdl/GoodByeService.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
            <wsdlFiles>
                <wsdlFile>GoodByeService.wsdl</wsdlFile>
            </wsdlFiles>
            <staleFile>
                ${project.build.directory}/jaxws/stale/GoodByeService.wsdl.stale
            </staleFile>
            <!-- packageName value for Id2 -->
            <packageName>com.test.goodbye.soap</packageName>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
    <target>2.1</target>
    <xjcArgs>
    <xjcArg>-XautoNameResolution</xjcArg>
    </xjcArgs>
    <bindingDirectory>src/jaxws</bindingDirectory>
    <keep>true</keep>
    <wsdlDirectory>src/jaxws/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
    <!-- packageName has been removed from here -->
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works for me.. How can i add url instead of this wsdl file int he configuration.

Comment: You mean access the WSDL file via HTTP not as a local file path? AFAIK the `<wsdlLocation>` element can contain an HTTP URL.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the configuration to be made in pom.xml but the wsdl2java tool has a -p option that will allow you to specify the package for each namespace separately. The syntax is [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html)